# how to pass parameters in body when sending request with Alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swiftui, alamofire

I have an api (nodejs) which saves my application data in MongoDB. But when I send the request, node throws an error which says that `score` is `undefined`

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'score' of undefined`

And when Xcode sends the request, the application works for about 30 seconds and then crashes and Xcode logs: `"The request timed out."`

this is my Swift code:

```swift
let parameters = ["score": scoreBoard]
print(parameters)
AF.request("http://localhost:4000/update/score", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseDecodable(of: [jsonData].self) {response in
                      let json = JSON(response.data!)[0]["score"]
                      scoreBoard = json.rawString()!
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Node I didn't use a body parser. When I included a body-parser then it was able to retrieve the data from the body.